# Access Twitter Fact Check Algorithm with `rtweet`

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I'm trying to access the Twitter API using the `R` package `rtweet`. Using the command `rtweet::get_timeline("@me")`, I'm able to pull the latest 100 tweets from the account @me. I'm trying to see if these tweets have a warning label on them, and if so what was the probability of them being labeled. I read twitter uses an algorithm to flag tweets with potential misinformation then sends them to human review. Is this information able to be seen?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious to learn otherwise, but I don't think those labels are exposed externally: https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/product/2020/updating-our-approach-to-misleading-information.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon. I tried reaching out to them for comment and still haven't heard anything. Will keep you posted!

Comment: These labels are not currently in the API. There is an open request for this to be added, but nothing on the public API roadmap at this time. https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com/forums/930250-twitter-api/suggestions/41967688-return-content-of-warning-labels-if-any